# Spreadsheet: Sum of dynamic number of rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have a table in my Google Spreadsheet that looks like this :

| Row | (A) Some day | (B) Some data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | day 1 | 5 |
| 2 | day 2 | 10 |
| 3 | **total** |  |
| 4 | day 1 | 8 |
| 5 | day 2 | 7 |
| 6 | day 3 | 9 |
| 7 | **total** |  |

Where I can have multiple "day rows", but I don't know how many. It can be only 1 like it can be 20 "day rows". And I want the "total row" to automatically do a SUM of the "day rows" above.

Result expected :

| Row | (A) Some day | (B) Some data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | day 1 | 5 |
| 2 | day 2 | 10 |
| 3 | **total** | **15** |
| 4 | day 1 | 8 |
| 5 | day 2 | 7 |
| 6 | day 3 | 9 |
| 7 | **total** | **24** |

Where B3 is equal to `SUM(B1:B2)` and B7 is equal to `SUM(B4:B6)`

I am trying to do that **without the App Script**, just using Spreadsheet native functions.

I think I should be using the [SUM function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093669?hl=en) or the [Query function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en), but I don't know how to dynamically get the right range. Do you have any idea how to do that ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

In your example, column **B** would be a mixture of constants and formulas.  That would require a script to deposit the formulas.  However with an extra column, you can avoid scripts.  In **C2** enter:

```
=if(A2<>"Total","",sum($B$1:$B1)-sum($C$1:C1))
```

and copy downwards:

[image]

Basically we add column **B** and subtract any previous Totals in column **C**.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to place the following single array formula in C1:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A:A="",, SUMIF(IF(ROW(A:A),ROW(A:A)), "<="&ROW(A:A),B:B) - SUMIF(IF(ROW(A:A), ROW(A:A)),"<="& VLOOKUP(ROW(A:A)-1, FILTER(ROW(A:A), A:A="total"), 1, TRUE), B:B)))`

If you only want to see the values for the "total" rows, change the opening

`IF(A:A=""`

to

`IF(A:A<>"total"`

The short version of how it works is that a sum is made of all values up to the current row in B:B, and from that is subtracted any values up to the last listing of the word "total" in A:A.

Answer (score 0):

paste in each cell in B column where A column = total

```
=INDEX(SUM(IFERROR(1*INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(INDEX(
 COUNTIFS({"total";A:A}, {"total";A:A}, {"total";A:A}, "=total", 
          {ROW(A:A);ROW()}, "<="&{ROW(A:A);ROW()})-1, ROW()+1, 1), 
 COUNTIFS({"total";A:A}, {"total";A:A}, {"total";A:A}, "=total", 
          {ROW(A:A);ROW()}, "<="&{ROW(A:A);ROW()}), 0), 2)&":"&
 ADDRESS(ROW()-1, 2)), 0)))
```

[image]